How to integrate Riverpod Provider State and page naviagtion
I have a categories widget with the following code:
build():
final meals = ref.watch(mealsProvider);

...
void _selectCategory(BuildContext context, Category category, List<Meal> meals) {
    
    final categorizedMeals =
        meals.where((meal) => meal.categories.contains(category.id)).toList();

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (ctx) => MealsScreen(
          title: category.title,
          meals: categorizedMeals,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

In the MealsScreen, I push MealDetails. In the MealDetails, I push CreateMeal. Finally in CreateMeal, I add or modify a meal in the mealsProvider. The ref.watch may rebuild the categories widget, but it doesn't affect the already pushed widgets. How can I rebuild the pushed widgets with the modified meal List?

The builder of Navigator.push runs only once when the route is pushed, and will not refresh even if the parent is updated. You should listen to the provider in the new Page.
void _selectCategory(BuildContext context, Category category, List<Meal> meals) {
    
    final categorizedMeals =
        meals.where((meal) => meal.categories.contains(category.id)).toList();

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (ctx) => MyWidget(

        ),
      ),
    );
  }

class MyWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final meals = ref.watch(mealsProvider);
    final categorizedMeals =
        meals.where((meal) => meal.categories.contains(category.id)).toList();
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}

